# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse?

Tags: node.js, https

Here I m using an HTTPS request inside another HTTPS request. Is that the main cause of this error?

```
const https = require("https");
https.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=India&limit=1&appid=e7f54903e0f4c0d93d70a0d9027bf6fc" , (res) => {
    res.on("data", data => {
        const info = JSON.parse(data.toString());
        const lat = info[0].lat;
        const lon = info[0].lon;
        https.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=e7f54903e0f4c0d93d70a0d9027bf6fc", (response) => {
            response.on("data", data => {
                console.log(data);
                const weatherData = JSON.parse(data.toString());   //At this line I am getting error.
                console.log(weatherData);
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` event comes in chunks. It's not full value. You need append data to a string and then on `end` event you will be able to get the whole response.

```
https.get("url" , (res) => {
  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => { .. do whatever u are doing with rawData .. });
});
```

Same thing for the next http request.

Check the [Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback) for more info.

Comment: I also did the same thing. I converted this buffer data to a javascript object by parsing. But when I try to do the same thing with nested request's data, I m getting an error.

Comment: You have to change the nested request to this type of thing as well. append in data event and process in end event.